# Nightwatch E2E-Test: Saving Image to Local Folder

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I want to save an image via Nightwatch to a local folder (e.g. /Downloads) to later select this picture again for testing the upload functionality.

My code so far:

`browser
  .url( 'http://172.28.128.11' )
  .waitForElementVisible( 'body' )
  .waitForElementVisible( '#profile-picture' )
  .moveToElement( '#profile-picture', 0, 0 )
  .mouseButtonClick( 'right' )
  .pause( 3000 );`

As an alternative, could I use the src attr of the image to perform a download?

Is it even possible to perform a right-click + save picture to local folder action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only give you part of an answer:

Right-Click wont be possible, because the context-menu is a feature of the used Browser and not the website you are testing.

If theres no download-function implemented it wont be possible to download a picture.

An alternative could be to save a screenshot to a local folder to test the upload functionality.